# ¿Cómo usar esta funcion?

Tags: c

Cuándo el usuario ingresa una cantidad de monedas, respecto a esa cantidad ingresada se le asigna un puntaje. Después hacer lo mismo con cantidad diamantes y sus puntos a guardarse. Al final tengo que hacer la suma de ambos puntos juntos. (en mi codigo esta los datos que tenia que asignar)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    int suma;

    suma = cantidad_energia(suma);
    printf ("La suma es: %i" , suma);

    return 0;
}

int cantidad_energia (int resultado){

    int resultado;
    int cantidad_monedas;
    int cantidad_diamantes;
    int puntos_monedas;
    int puntos_diamantes;

    printf ("Ingrese cantidad de monedas (0-100)");
    scanf( "%i", &cantidad_monedas);

    printf ("Ingrese cantidad de diamantes (0-4)");
    scanf("%i", &cantidad_diamantes);

        if (cantidad_monedas>=0 && cantidad_monedas <= 10 )
    puntos_monedas = 1;
        if (cantidad_monedas>10 && cantidad_monedas <= 20 )
    puntos_monedas = 2;
        if (cantidad_monedas>20 && cantidad_monedas <=30 )
    puntos_monedas = 3;
        if (cantidad_monedas>30 && cantidad_monedas <= 40 )
    puntos_monedas = 4;
        if (cantidad_monedas>40 && cantidad_monedas <= 50 )
    puntos_monedas = 5;
        if (cantidad_monedas>50 && cantidad_monedas <= 60 )
    puntos_monedas = 1;
        if (cantidad_monedas>60 && cantidad_monedas <= 70 )
    puntos_monedas = 2;
        if (cantidad_monedas>70 && cantidad_monedas <= 80 )
    puntos_monedas = 3;
        if (cantidad_monedas>80 && cantidad_monedas <= 90 )
    puntos_monedas = 4;
        if (cantidad_monedas>=90 && cantidad_monedas <= 100 )
    puntos_monedas = 5;

    if (cantidad_diamantes=0)
    puntos_diamantes= 0;
        if (cantidad_diamantes=1)
    puntos_diamantes= 1;
        if (cantidad_diamantes=2)
    puntos_diamantes= 2;
        if (cantidad_diamantes=3)
    puntos_diamantes= 3;
        if (cantidad_diamantes=4)
    puntos_diamantes= 4;

    return resultado = puntos_monedas + puntos_diamantes;

}
```

Comment: Hola por lo visto en la funcion int no le estarias pasando parametros cuando la declaras, pero si cuando la llamas no se si ese sera el problema. Saludos

Comment: Cual seria el problema?

Comment: A la función le pasas un entero que luego no usas para nada. Dentro defines otro entero con el mismo nombre que tampoco usas para nada porque en el return le asignas al suma a la variable resultado para hacer el return. La variable resultado te sobra. Y después de todo esto, como te pregunta @gbianchi: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: El problema es que no suma según los valores que le asigne cuando ingreso por teclado

Comment: Seria interesante que miraras [ask]. Las preguntas deben ser claras. de paso, vuelve a mirar el [tour]. Aceptar las respuestas que contestan tu pregunta es una parte importante de la utilización del sitio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a explicar dos características del lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c), ambas están sucediendo en tu código.

1. En C puedes usar números en condiciones, se considera que un valor cero es falso y un valor diferente a cero es verdadero.

   ```
   if (0) // Falso
   if (123456789) // Verdadero.
   ```
2. Una expresión de asignación de valor, devuelve la variable asignada.

   ```
   int a = 1;
   int b = 42;
   int c = a = b; // Primero asigna 'b' a 'a', devuelve 'a' y finalmente asigna 'a' a 'c'.
                  // 'c' obtiene el valor '42.
   ```

En tu función `cantidad_energia` estás haciendo asignaciones en condiciones:

```
    if (cantidad_diamantes=0) // asigna '0' a 'cantidad_diamantes'
puntos_diamantes= 0;
    if (cantidad_diamantes=1) // asigna '1' a 'cantidad_diamantes'
puntos_diamantes= 1;
    if (cantidad_diamantes=2) // asigna '2' a 'cantidad_diamantes'
puntos_diamantes= 2;
    if (cantidad_diamantes=3) // asigna '3' a 'cantidad_diamantes'
puntos_diamantes= 3;
    if (cantidad_diamantes=4) // asigna '4' a 'cantidad_diamantes'
puntos_diamantes= 4;
```

Después de la asignación, se devuelve la variable `cantidad_diamantes` que se usa en la comparación, tu código equivale a:

```
    if (0) // falso
puntos_diamantes= 0;
    if (1) // verdadero
puntos_diamantes= 1;
    if (2) // verdadero
puntos_diamantes= 2;
    if (3) // verdadero
puntos_diamantes= 3;
    if (4) // verdadero
puntos_diamantes= 4;
```

Como todas las condiciones se ejecutan secuencialmente, al final `puntos_diamantes` **siempre acaba valiendo `4`**.

Por otro lado, si `cantidad_monedas` es mayor o igual a cien, usas el valor de `puntos_monedas` sin inicializar, que puede tener un valor cualquiera… tampoco se si tiene sentido obtener los mismos puntos por diez monedas que por sesenta o es un error de copiapegado tuyo, si corriges todos los fallos mencionados y en lugar de fuerza bruta usas matemáticas tu código podría parecerse a:

```
int cantidad_energia (){

    int cantidad_monedas;
    int cantidad_diamantes;

    printf ("Ingrese cantidad de monedas (0-100)");
    scanf( "%i", &cantidad_monedas);

    printf ("Ingrese cantidad de diamantes (0-4)");
    scanf("%i", &cantidad_diamantes);

    return (1 + ((cantidad_monedas / 10) % 5)) + cantidad_diamantes;
}
```